# How to get appdynamics to detect Apache Camel Business Transactions

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, karaf, appdynamics

has anybody gotten Appdynamics java agent to detect Apache Camel business transactions? Picking up files from a directory (polling) and then sending off to activemq.

Another case is camel deployed on apache karaf, need to track outgoing http calls using appDynamics

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the critical point for AppDynamics (or profilers like that) it is essential to find an entry point. Usually the prefered way is to have an Servlet "Endpoint" that starts a threat and can be followed. 
For the scenario you are describing this wouldn't work as it's missing the "trigger" to start the following. Most likely you'll need to build your own app-dynamics monitoring extension for it.

Answer (score 0):

By default much of the Apache stuff is excluded.  Try adding Call Graph Settings (Configure >> Instrumentation >> Call Graph Settings), to include specific transports, like org.apache.camel.component.file.* in the Specific sub-packages / classes from the Excluded Packages to be included in call graphs section.  Do not include org.apache.camel.* as it will instrument all the camel code which is very expensive.  You may want to do it at first to detect what you want to watch, but make sure to change it back.

Comment: no success, yet.. no business transactions even using org.apache.camel.* in the agent config file

Comment: Try adding transaction detection in Configure >> Instrumentation >> Transaction Detection >> Custom Match Rules for a POJO: org.apache.camel.*.  Start watching the BTs that flow in and choose the ones you really want, setup rules for those and call graph settings for them too.  Then remove the org.apache.camel.* rule.

Answer (score 0):

Edit AppServerAgent\conf\app-agent-config.xml:

```
--under-->
<app-agent-configuration>
    <agent-services>
        <agent-service name="TransactionMonitoringService" enable="true">
            <configuration-properties>
--add-->        <property name="enable-async-correlation-for" value="camel"/>
```

From the Controller web site:

Configure >> Instrumentation >> Call Graph Settings
Add Always Shown Package/Class: org.apache.camel.*

Servers >> App Servers >> {tiername} >> {nodename} >> Agents
App Server Agent
Configure
Use Custom Configuration
find-entry-points: true

Comment: Also, see this link: http://community.appdynamics.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/Find-Entry-Points/ta-p/14065